# Prevent a field in a datasheet from being edited (MS Access 2010)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I know that a datasheet form can be set to only Allow Additions and NOT Edits, but is it possible to make a field editable only if it is blank?  I tried setting the field to enabled=false if the field has data in it, but then the whole datasheet becomes disabled.  The purpose for this functionality is to prevent users from changing their entry once completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lock it when entering or clicking the control:

```
Private Sub YourTextbox_GotFocus()

    Me!YourTextbox.Locked = Not IsNull(Me!YourTextbox.Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: Precisely.  Thank you.